How to create an IAM policy granting full access to all resources and S3 buckets, except one specific bucket (read-only-bucket) with read-only access?
How can I modify the following AWS IAM policy to grant read access to a specific bucket (my-read-only-bucket) while ensuring full access to all other buckets? The current policy blocks write access to all buckets, but I need to update it accordingly.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "FullAccessToAllResources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyWriteAccessToSpecificBucket",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-read-only-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-read-only-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadAccessToSpecificBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-read-only-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-read-only-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}



Use Deny with NotAction. Negative of Negative results in positive. Hence, Using Deny with NotAction means Deny all actions except the ones added in NotAction.
Hence, a combination of the two json will work.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "allow-all-bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "negative-of-negative",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-read-only-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-read-only-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

